# Active directory overwriting existing computers

Tags: active-directory

while adding another user with same computer name active directory i overwriting old one. Is there any way to prevent this?

I mean can i get some message or access denied when i try to add second computer with the same computer name as other that is already in active directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can't join to the DC with a computer with the same name that another previously added in the AD and is already running. You get an error when you try this in Windows OS.